# How can I put the video page link in the text of the iframe on the jwplayer

Tags: javascript, video, embed, blogger, jwplayer

In my video player, I put a share button on the network,  embed video
How do I put the video's private page link in the embedding text

```html
<div id="player" >
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/libraries/8ygHoiAH.js"></script>
<script>
jwplayer('player').setup({
   file: 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4',
            sharing: {
            code:'<iframe src="link-page-Video" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>',
    sites:["facebook","twitter"]
},
   
     }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to have it in the video menu itself.

JWPlayer provide some information on setting up the Sharing link in their online documentation.

An example from that for quick reference:

```js
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
  playlist: "http://cdn.jwplayer.com/media/1234abcD",
  sharing: {
    sites: ["facebook","twitter","email","linkedin","pinterest"]
  },
  intl: {
    en: {
      sharing: {
        heading: "Share this awesome video"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

More details here: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-enable-viewers-to-share-your-content